# Why do I get an error message that .attr is not a function?

Tags: jquery, attr

This is an extremely simple, very basic, page--I am an absolute beginner with JavaScript/jQuery (an artist/philosopher, not a Website developer). I can't get the .attr jQuery function to work.

I've located answers re ".attr is not a function" but the codes are complex and I cannot understand the explanations.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Sample HTML</title>
<script src="jQ/jQuery.js"></script>
<script>
$("document").ready(function( ) {
var juneau=('#anchorage').attr('width');
alert(juneau);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id='anchorage' src='game.jpg' height='300' width='300'></img>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected to get an alert saying '300px', but nothing happens and the explanation is "'#anchorage'.attr is not a function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing $ in selection - var juneau=$('#anchorage').attr('width');

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your overall HTML, but the Javascript bits that you are most concerned with should look like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  var juneau = $('#anchorage').attr('width');
  alert(juneau);
});
</script>
```

Notice I am using a shorthand anonymous function, which is equivalent to "on document ready".

Hope this helps.